# S5 "Recommended Apps" & "Toolbox" crashed when selected

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, crashes

I just got my new S5 and I restored system data from Titanium Backup from my old S3 which crashed the "Recommended apps" and "Toolbox" functions when selected in Settings.

When either of these two were selected,  the message "Unfortunately, Settings have stopped" appeared.

I'm running Samsung stock ROM Lollipop 5.0. Are there any ways to restore these two settings by flashing some zip files?

Comment: I don't think both your phones are running the exact build of Android, and so, you shouldn't go for restoring System Data. To which Android version does your backup of S3 belongs to?

Comment: My S3 is running 4.3 Jelly Bean.